# not able to set cookie on angular client hosted other than 'localhost'

Tags: angular, express, cookies

using express server as backend and angular client as frontend
express hosted at 3001 port and angular on 4200
when working with localhost everything works fine

when hosted angular on IP address something like - 10.125...:4200
and couldn't find cookie on browser

tried to set domain, path everything
nothing worked

also tried res.cookie() method, same result
here is browser image (where no cookie being set) -
[browser cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuaKS.png)

here is my code in express js (index.js file) -

[setting cookie in express js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERv04.png)

Comment: How did you configure the cookies? Did you set anything to SameSite attribute?

Comment: no i didn't set anything in SameSite attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too allow usage of cookies between different domains, you must set your cookies SameSite attribute to None so something like this:

```
return res.cookies('cookieName', data, {sameSite: 'None'}).status(200).send();
```